# Doctrine cache relations

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, redis

I have a Entity 'Category' which has a relation to Many 'Projects' which in term has many 'Images'.

I'm caching the results inside the 'Category' repository to fetch all project linked to that category with some conditions. Caching is done with the redisBundle and the doctrine: query->setResultCacheDriver functions:

```
try {


        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb->select('Category', 'Projects')
            ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Category', 'Category')
            ->leftJoin(
                'Category.projects',
                'Projects',
                \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
                $qb->expr()->eq('Projects.active', 1)
            )
            ->where(
                $qb->expr()->eq('Category.slug', ':slug')
            )
            ->setParameter('slug', $slug);

        $query = $qb->getQuery();

        $query
            ->setResultCacheDriver($this->cacheDriver)
            ->setResultCacheLifetime($this->cacheLifetime);

        return $query->getOneOrNullResult();

    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
```

I'm looping throught the projects in the view and display some imags of each project.

Is it possible to cache those queries to? Im now getting 1 query for each project to fetch its Images.

Comment: If you join images & add it to the select the same way you have for projects it should cache just fine.

Comment: Actually, caching aside, the reason you're getting an image query per category is because you're lazy loading images. Left join images to categories and add images to your select and you're all good.

Comment: @Richard post it as an answer :)

Comment: @JakubZalas true that, done

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing with cache isn't the issue. The reason you're getting an image query per category is because you're lazy loading images. Left join images to categories and add images to your select and you're all good.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the solution!